# How to take an item from a list and match it with another item in another list in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

I have 2 lists in my class which both contain strings, I am using *winforms*:

```
public List<Journey> journeys = new List<Journey>();
public List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
```

I want to be able to take e.g the first element in the list `journeys` and the first element in the list `vehicles`, combine the data and then output that data to a listbox called `ShowAll`.

I want to be able to do this with every item in the lists, so 2nd element in `journeys` matches with 2nd element in `vehicles` and 3rd element in `journeys` matches with 3rd element in `vehicles` etc.

I don't have a clue how to do this but it would be great if anyone could give me a hand. Thanks!

Comment: suggest a `CompositeObject` containing a `Journey` and a `Vehicle`, and just having one list of that `CompositeObject`. with a tostring for entering into the listbox..

Comment: Would you kindly show me some example code for that? @amdixon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
class CompositeObject //use a better name that fits your context..
{
  Journey journey; public Journey Property { get; private set; }
  Vehicle vehicle; public Vehicle Property { get; private set; }

  public CompositeObject(Journey journey, Vehicle vehicle)
  {
    this.journey = journey;
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return this.vehicle.ToString() + " | " + this.journey.ToString();
  }
}
```

now you can refactor the `ToString` to give you output suitable for your gui (the listbox). and when it comes to writing into the listbox a simple for-loop should do

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this. I just wrote it here but it should work. Give it a shot.

Good Luck.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int n=0; n< journeys.Length; journeys++)
    sb.Append(journeys[n]).Append(vehicles[n]).Append("\n");

ShowAll.Clear();
ShowAll.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This works to an extent, it seems to be working but when I output it to a textbox or anything, it just outputs the name of the lists rather than any data.

Comment: I was assuming arrays of strings. Try journeys[n].ToString()

Comment: List<Journey> and List<Vehicle> are lists of strings. They should be List<string> if that is what you are going after.